# Determine the number of a specific component in a Modelica model at translation (using Dymola)

Tags: modelica, dymola

How could you determine the number of instances of a given class within this model at translation.  This size is to be used to set the size of a vector.

```
model ModelToBeCounted
end ModelToBeCounted;
  
model Example
  ModelToBeCounted A;
  ModelToBeCounted B;
  ModelToBeCounted C;
end Example;
```

So in this example I would like to like to determine the number instances of `ModelToBeCounted`.  These instances could also be within instances of other classes.  The code at the top level could be altered to do this and the `ModelToBeCounted` could also be altered.

I tried using external objects however I could not find a way to ensure that the external objects are all created before the function used to report the total number of external objects was run.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **can** modify the model `ModelToBeCounted` you can do this using `inner/outer`:

```
  connector C
    Real totalNum;
    flow Real addNum;
  end C;

  model InnerObjectCounter
    C c;
  equation 
    c.totalNum+c.addNum=0 "Correct sign";
    annotation(missingInnerMessage="Add inner component to count objects");
  end InnerObjectCounter;

  model FlowSource
    C c;
  equation 
    c.addNum=1;
  end FlowSource;


  model AddCounter
    outer InnerObjectCounter objectCounter;
    final Integer totalNum=integer(flowSource.c.totalNum);
    FlowSource flowSource;
  equation 
    connect(flowSource.c, objectCounter.c);
  end AddCounter;

  model ModelToBeCounted
    AddCounter c;
  end ModelToBeCounted;
```

All components are automatically connected to the inner object using inner/outer-mechanism, and they have a flow of 1 that is summed together.

If you **cannot** modify the model `ModelToBeCounted`, and you are willing to use *non-standarized methods* you can set the flag:

```
Hidden.AllowAutomaticInstanceOf=true;
```

and then use:

```
final parameter Integer m=sum(1 for m in P.ModelToBeCounted);
```

From:
https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/blob/MCP/0021/RationaleMCP/0021/

Comment: Thanks, Is the FlowSource code missing from the code above?  
Is this just a flow source setting c.addNum to 1?

Comment: Yes have added it now

Comment: As I would want to use totalNum to set the size of a vector the first option will not work.  The second option is very interesting and exactly what I am looking for pity it is not standard Modelica.  However the first example solves the overall feature I wanted to add to my model!  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `ModelManagement` library can do that.

In fact, there is exactly what you need available as a function:

```
ModelManagement.Structure.Instantiated.CountUsedModels("Example", {"ModelToBeCounted"});
= {3}
```

The library is installed with Dymola and available with the standard license.
You just have to open it from the *Libraries* menu.

A problem could be, that this function has to translate your model. I am not sure how well this will work for your requirement:

> This size is to be used to set the size of a vector.

Comment: Unfortunately ModelManagement.Structure.Instantiated.CountUsedModels is an interactive function so cannot be used within a model.

Comment: You could write a script, which first uses `CountUsedModels` to determine the vector size and then simulates the model (e.g. with `simulateModel("Example(vectorSize="+String(value)+")")` or with `simulateExtendedModel`)

Comment: Thanks that is really good however I would need it to be more automated than that.  Basically I have a model that currently runs and want to make a modification and it must continue to run in the same fashion.  So the user should not need to modify how they use the model.   If think I have found a workaround where I create a vector that is larger then the number of instances and then assign to this, when I have it working I'll post it.   Thanks for the help